# Is there a weather application that also shows the current season?

Tags: unix, weather

All I found never shows the season info.
Also, of course, it must be to my location (it must consider latitude and longitude).
I don't understand why they all don't have that simple information that I always wanted to know, well...

My target OS is Ubuntu.
But any Linux app would do.
Also, if there is only a Windows app, I may try to run it thru Wine.
Not paid apps though.